# Javascript check if undefined doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined

I want to check if a object  is defined or not..

content of the Object:

[image: Object]

so I'll do:

```
if (e.model.item.state  != "undefined"){
var stateID = e.model.item.state.id;
....
}
else{

}
```

Then e.model.item.state is undefined but it does enter the if clause and stops here:

```
var stateID = e.model.item.state.id;
```

because of undefined..!

I tried also:

```
 !== "undefined"
 !=== "undefined"
```

Comment: `undefined` !== `"undefined"` (`typeof undefined === "undefined"` though)

Comment: use `void 0` whenever you need to refer undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, you can check whether a variable is either `undefined`, `null`, `false` or `0` by just simply doing,

```
if (e.model.item.state) {
   // e.model.item.state is NOT `undefined`, `null`, `false` or `0`
}
else {
   // e.model.item.state is either `undefined`, `null`, `false` or `0`
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better use this to avoid unnecessary `undefined error`:-

```
if (e && e.model && e.model.item & e.model.item.state) {
   // e.model.item.state is NOT `undefined`, `null`, `false` or `0`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`"undefined"` is not the same as `undefined`. The first one is a string with the word 'undefined' in it, the other is a reserved js term for undefined var.

Doing `something == "undefined"` is comparing it to a string. You should remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You check for `undefined` in one of following ways:

`var a;`

`if( a === undefined )`

**OR**

`if( typeof a === "undefined" )`

`"undefined"` is not equal to `undefined`. So, if you compare directly for equality, use it without quotes. If you are using `typeof` operator, you need to use quotes because `typeof` always returns a string value.